# IIS7 + PHP + HTTP POST = hang?

Tags: php, windows, iis, iis-7, http-post

I installed PHP on a Windows 7 x64 machine with IIS7 via Windows Web App Gallery. Everything seemed to go fine, and a simple phpinfo() page works like you would think. However, whenever I do a POST request to a PHP page, the request just hangs forever. See the very simple test page below... It doesn't even have any dynamic content in it.

I've wasted way too much time on this. Any ideas? Thanks a bunch!

page.php:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <form action="page.php" method="post">
   <textarea name="apa"></textarea>
   <input type="submit" value="ok" />
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Handler mapping:

```
<handlers>
        <add name="PHP_via_FastCGI" path="*.php" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Script" />
</handlers>
```

Comment: Im not really a windows gut but i seem to remember that when using IIS (this would have been a version or 2 ago under Small Business Server) i had to specifically allow a POST request on the virtual host (or whatever the name of that entity is under IIS). But i was running it as a module i think, not as CGI so i dont know for sure if thats relevant...Also, you might get better responses if you post this on Serverfault instead of SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much troubleshooting, it turned out that this line in my web.config file was causing the issue:

```
<trace enabled="true" localOnly="false" pageOutput="false" requestLimit="40" />
```

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem. Any PHP POST to another PHP page was hanging. In the process of rebuilding the web.config file from scratch, I found an error message that suggested running the AppPool **Managed pipeline mode** in Classic mode.

After making the above change, my PHP code is working as expected.

Comment: Same here.  I had a sub-directory inside an ASP.NET site, so I just converted the folder to an Application in IIS and made a new app pool for it (In Classic Mode)

Comment: How can this be done ? Do I need access to the server?

Answer (score 0):

This was driving me nuts too, tryin g to bolt on some PHP Codeigniter pages to an ASP.NET site. Configuring the PHP applications subfolder as an application and running in a Classic ASP.NET Application Pool did the trick.