# Windows Server 2012: IIS8 with PHP hangs on every POST

Tags: php, windows-server-2012, iis-8

I have a server runnig Windows Server 2012, installed IIS with PHP 5.3.24 and wincache and installed MediaWiki and phpMyAdmin everything is running well except when I do a post to the server, so when I login to MediaWiki and try to edit a page it seems to work well until i hit that "save" button then the page just hangs in loading.

The change is saved to the database and no errors is logged in Event Viewer or the PHP error-log. There is a Request for the Worker Process but nothing happens:
http://blackhole.obscured.se/image/2s222j0P3p16

The "Time Elapsed" just goes on untill timeout:

HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exceeded configured request timeout

I've tried to disable the wincache but with no success. and getting a bit frustrated, anyone know what this could be?

After som digging the HTTPERR file shows (Connection_Abandoned_By_ReqQueue), so the browser get that after timeout.

2013-07-16 09:43:08 81.94.163.36 POST /index.php title=Main_Page&action=submit 80 - 194.14.32.4 Mozilla/5.0+(Macintosh;+Intel+Mac+OS+X+10_8_4)+AppleWebKit/536.30.1+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Version/6.0.5+Safari/536.30.1 http://www.domain.tld/index.php?title=Main_Page&action=edit 500 0 1 579697

Comment: Difficult to guess here.  I would recommend you eliminate possible causes in the code before assuming it is related to the server.  Kill the script `die()` at points in the `POST` process until the hang stops.  You can then narrow down the cause.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the problem is not application specific. I've installed MediaWiki, phpMyAdmin and WordPress and all of them experience the same problem when doing a POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can this be of any use? [IIS7 + PHP + HTTP POST = hang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357636/iis7-php-http-post-hang)
The answer from breese seems to be a solution.